# Put input fields inline - bootstrap v3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here I have a bootstrap form v3 and I try to make this form to be inline so ha,ar,m2 to be inline... I have:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="naziv">Naziv</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="naziv" name="naziv" type="text" placeholder="naziv parcele" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Appended Input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ha">Povrsina</label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="ha" name="ha" class="form-control" placeholder="ha" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">ha</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Appended Input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ar"></label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="ar" name="ar" class="form-control" placeholder="ar" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">ar</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Appended Input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="m2"></label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="m2" name="m2" class="form-control" placeholder="m2" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">m2</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

But how I can put `#ha`, `#ar`, `#m2` elements inline so in the same row?

Any idea?
I try with `form-inline` but dont work.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3490/embedded/result/)

Comment: what about the input's caption like: `Povrsina`?

Comment: This is text that must be on first position in inline row

Comment: put #ar and #m2 to the form-group of #ha

Comment: please update jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3490/embedded/result/ to see

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsbin.com/jipus/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to keep the inputs in one row, you could put the columns containing `.input-group` in one `form-group` element, as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="ha">Povrsina</label>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="ha" name="ha" class="form-control" placeholder="ha" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-addon">ha</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="ar" name="ar" class="form-control" placeholder="ar" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-addon">ar</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="m2" name="m2" class="form-control" placeholder="m2" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-addon">m2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jipus/2/edit)**.

Note that you should change the class names of the columns within your own demo to prevent exceeding the 12-column grid.